# How to get SaveAs Dialog Box to show in browser for a file download from ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to download a .mp4 file from an ASP.Net Core 3.1 server to the browser. The problem is when I receive the response it doesn't automatically bring up the save as dialog box or just save the file as I have read elsewhere. How can get the save as dialog to pop up when the file returns?

API call from button onClick. I believe this is where the problem lies.

```
function DownloadFile(id) {
    var url = "https://localhost:44340/api/Update/";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: `${url}${encodeURI(id)}`,
        contentType: "application/octet-stream",
        success: function (result) {
            //This is where I think the save as dialog box should pop up. Not sure how to make that happen.
        }
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
// GET: api/MovieDownload/string
[HttpGet("{path}")]
public IActionResult GetMovieDownload([FromRoute] string path)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

    if (stream == null)
        return NotFound();
    
    return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)); 
}
```

This is the response I get when I test the API directly with Swagger.
[image: Swagger-Response-Capture.png]

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You’re downloading the file via AJAX, so of course the user doesn’t get a download dialog by the browser because your AJAX code is responsible of doing something with the response. If you want to trigger a download dialog, you should just redirect the user to that URL. For example by doing `window.location = "https://localhost:44340/api/Update/"`. You could also trigger a download from the AJAX response but if your files are large (which it sounds like), then that will be rather inefficient unless you add some custom streaming support.

Comment: I suspected the ajax call could be the culprit. Could I just return the redirect from the server? Like `return Redirect(stringFullUrl)`?